# GTK: g_signal_connect() send wrong address

Tags: c, gtk

I have this piece of code:

```
int gui_showScore(struct Game *game)
{
    printf("%p\n", game);
    return NO_ERROR;
}

int gui_createButtonShowScore(GtkWidget *fixed, GtkWidget **showScore,
                          struct Game *game)
{
    if (fixed == NULL)
        return POINTER_NULL;

    printf("%p\n", game);
    *showScore = gtk_button_new_with_label("Show score");
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), *showScore, 620, 50);
    gtk_widget_show(*showScore);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(*showScore), "clicked",
                     G_CALLBACK(gui_showScore), game);

    return NO_ERROR;
}
```

Why when is pressed the button, is called gui_showScore() with other pointer?

e.g: In gui_createButtonShowScore() the pointer value game is 0x1249590 and when is pressed the button is called gui_showScore() and the pointer value game is 0x12202b0. Why?

How can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the [documentation for the "clicked" signal](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkButton.html#GtkButton-clicked):

```
void user_function(GtkButton *button, gpointer   user_data)
```

The first argument is always always the object that received the signal, the *last* argument is the user pointer where the data supplied when you connected the handler is passed.